# selected spinner items not display on seperate editbox

Tags: android

I am new in android app development. My question is when I am click on submit button those select spinner items are not display on separate editbox.only nullnullnull value show on edit box in edit box. when I am click on btnSubmit1 only nullnullnull value display on edirbox

```
btnSubmit1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            /*Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/
            display.setText("Facility-:"+Spinner1Value+"\n"+"Trip-:"+Spinner2Value+"\n"+"ShiftType-:"+Spinner3Value);
            //display.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });}
    public void addItemsOnSpinner(){
        spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.facility_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);   
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);




spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {                                     
       try
       {
       Spinner1Value= spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Spinner1Value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          // Spinner1Value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     Spinner1Value=String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error::"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       //EditText1.setText(Spinner1Value);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {                                     
       try
       {
        //   Spinner2Value=String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Spinner2Value= parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
           //Spinner2Value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error::"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       //EditText1.setText(Spinner1Value);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {                                     
       try
       {
        Spinner3Value= spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
           //Spinner3Value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
          // Spinner3Value=String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString());
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error::"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       //EditText1.setText(Spinner1Value);

    }



    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you clarify where Spinner1Value, Spinner2Value, Spinner3Value are defined?

Answer (score 0):

rather than assigning the value of spinner onItemSelected, have you tried reassign the value of Spinner at btnSubmit1 onClick event?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Spinner1Value = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Spinner2Value = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Spinner3Value = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        display.setText("Facility-:"+Spinner1Value+"\n"+"Trip-:"+Spinner2Value+"\n"+"ShiftType-:"+Spinner3Value);
    }
```

You might need a function to make sure that each Spinner has been selected or you could set the default selectedItem on each Spinner beforehand though.